# How to capture exports of a javascript file when using Browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify, webpack

if I have a javascript file with the contents:

```
(function() {
  return function (foo) {
    return foo + "bar";
  };
}());
```

is it possible to capture the return value from that file in a variable somehow?  I'm assuming the function is returned to the auto instantiating parens and then garbage collected, but I'm not sure.

As an aside, I'm trying to expose a browserified collection of node modules to the window for testing purposes (I realize there are probably other methods for going about this, but I'm curious about this one).

Comment: Don't think so, unless you ajaxed it in as plain text and manipulated it a little bit before eval'n it.

Comment: nope. you should use some form of callbacks.

Comment: Files don't have return values, functions do. And yes, since the return isn't assigned to a variable there will be no references to it and it will get garbage collected.

Comment: @All - That's what I was assuming.  I'm not that familiar with AMD, so I wasn't sure if there was some kind of onload trick I'm not familiar with and wanted to confirm.  Thanks.

Comment: Anybody want to swap a comment for an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files that are included with browserify (or other CommonJS compatible system) can expose methods or values to the requiring file via `module.exports`. `module.exports` is returned from the `require()` statement.

Take this example:

**index.js**

```
var myClass = require("myClass");
```

**myClass.js**

```
module.exports = (function() {
    return function (foo) {
        return foo + "bar";
    };
}());
```

index.js now has access to the function that is built in myClass.js and can use it as:

**index.js**

```
var myClass = require("myClass");
// expose the class to the global scope
window.myClass = myClass;
var result = myClass("foo ");
```

so the var `result` would have the value `"foo bar"`.

Comment: Great answer to a slightly different question! :) My question in this case is how to run those tests from the browser.  Working on a video player architecture with a lot of potential for cross browser inconsistencies, so I need some way to unit test the player components in a browser matrix.

Comment: This works in the browser if you're using browserify.

Comment: By that I assume you mean it creates a common closure where I can place tests that have access to the module that run in the browser?  Or do you mean that there is a way I can load the browserified script and extract the module by calling require("myClass")?

Comment: I ask because the first option is where I started based on the link here:  http://substack.net/how_I_write_tests_for_node_and_the_browser which I believe is in line with your suggestion.

Comment: In my example, index.js could be the test rig, built with browserify. From there you can access all of the exports of each module.

Comment: Got it...  Can you modify your answer to include this can't be done in the browser for future readers (who are skimming) since that was the question and I'll accept?

Comment: Oh but you can. I went back and re-read the question and it looks like the only thing missing here is actually getting to global scope. I modified the answer to expose the module to `window`.